# How do I extract floating point values from .txt file to use for calculation in python?

Tags: python

```
count = 0
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") :
        print(line)
        count = count + 1
print(count)
```

There is a file with 27 lines like X-DSPAM-Confidence :  0.xxxxx, I need to extract the numerical value from each of them to be used for calculations.

Comment: Is the comma at the end of your example line in the file?

Comment: Have you tried using regex? or if it's a fixed length value, have you tried slicing the string?

Comment: @andreihondrari why is there a need for regex here?

Comment: @ycx it's just an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `split(':')`:

Code:

```
count = 0
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") :
        print(line)
        value = line.split(':')[-1]  # will split line into 'X-DSPAM-Confidence' and 'value'
        # if you have ',' at the end of the line, simply do this:
        value = value.strip(',')
        value = float(value)
        print(value)
        count = count + 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the format is exactly as you described it, you can use the code below:

```
float(line.split(':')[1])
```

If there's more variation in the text than what you described, you might need to try regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.rfind(':')` to get the position of `:` and then do a string slice to get the value.

```
count = 0
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") :
        print(line)
        value = line[line.rfind(':'):]  # will take the last occurrence of : to slice the line
        print(value)
        count = count + 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
pos = 0
ans = None
total = 0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : 
        continue
    else :
        count = count + 1
        pos = line.find(':')
        ans = line[pos+1 : ]
        total = total + float(ans)
avg = total/count
```

Comment: Please, add some notes and explanations.

Comment: if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : >>> by this I am just specifying that I only need floating points from this type of line.....pos = line.find(':') >>>as the floating points are after the ':' so I am retriving the position  of colon so that I can extract the floating points number after the colon......ans = line[pos+1 : ] >>> by this I am extracting the floating points after the colon position.that's why I adder pos+1 as pos is the position of the colon

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
val = 0
count = 0
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") :
        count = count + 1
        val=val + float(line[line.find('0'):])
    elif not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") :
        continue
print("Average spam confidence:",val/count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input("Enter file name:")
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
s=0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    count = count+1
    pos = line.find('0')
    floatingP = float(line[pos:])
    s += floatingP
print(s/count)
```